# ODBC: add drivers under system dns not visible

Tags: java, database, odbc, drivers

My OS is `windows10 64bit`. I want to connect my java application to `MicrosoftAccessDriver(*mdb,*accdb)`. But when i go to `add` under odbc64 system dsn it shows only sql server.  But on odbc32 it shows everything. I have tried running `c/windows/system32/odbcad32.exe` and as well as `c/windows/syswow64/odbcad32.exe`My java is 32 bit.
And in the user dsn by default it shows MicrosoftAccessDriver and mentioned 32bit under platform. I have attached screenshots [add under system dsn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yud9.png)  and [user dsn default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExAFv.png). Can anyone guide my how to connect my application to database? And what should i prefer `odbc32` or `odbc64`?

Comment: why the java tag?

Comment: Because i m trying to connect database to my java application

Comment: what is the java version and what is the version of office ?

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: ms office 2010, jdk 7

Comment: what jdbc driver means? I cant understand bro

Comment: if the jdk version is 8 then jdbc odbc driver is no more part of jdk 8. But the following may help [http://bigfatball.blogspot.in/2016/03/how-to-enable-jdbc-odbc-bridge-for-jdk-8.html]

Comment: @vijay Sorry the link is not opening..

Comment: This may help: https://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all you must have a database created in access 2000. 
After that
Goto Windows\Syswow64 folder
Click on odbcad32.exe
```

Under User DSN click on add.
   choose microsoft access driver (*.mdb ,*.accdb).
   Now type a dsn name.
   and select the database that you had created.
   use the same name of dsn in your java program.
   compile and run your java program.

Following is a sample Java database connectivity program:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/SimpleexampleofJDBCODBCfunctionality.htm

Comment: uh Sorry i forgot to mention one thing.. In control panel under programs its shown java-32bit. What should i do? Should i go for odbc 32 bit or odbc 64? And my access is 2007

Comment: click on odbcad32.exe. this is used for the 32 bit version drivers on 64 bit os like windows 10 64 bit. I have checked on my system. It is working fine.

Comment: I have tried by connecting 32 bit driver But it showed up `driver source name not found exception` after build

Comment: check your dsn name. Is it matching with the the dsn name that you have created.

Comment: yeah, when i set connectivity under odbc32 it works. But when i run the build jar file in another, caught error dsn not found. After long searches got suggestions to make connectivity under odbc64. Then  the situation is as mentioned in question